# How to build Sequential model for multiple outputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

This is a Classification problem (multiclass multioutput). I want Sequential model to give 3 outputs. Below is the required code. Whatever I do its throwing me errors. I have tried training data using TimeDistributed and Flattening. But I dont understand how to resolve it.
The dataset has 9285 rows, 7803 features.

this is the shape of `input data = (9285, 7803, 1)` (sample, features, timestep) `ytrain shape = (9285, 3)`

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1500,input_shape=(7803,1), return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(100,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

hist=model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,epochs=10,batch_size=64)
```

this is the error

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:789 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:201 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:141 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:245 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:1666 categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:4839 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 7803, 3) are incompatible
```

Can someone please guide me how to resolve it or share some source from where I can learn.This is my first attempt of training data using LSTM so I am little lost or **Can I get 3 outputs without using LSTM**

Comment: Try `return_sequences=False` on the middle layer. Currently it produces a state for each of 7803 inputs

Comment: @Marat  `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 500, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 500, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_input'), name='lstm_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 7703, 1).
4/4 [==============================] - 185s 45s/step - loss: 535849.8125 - accuracy: 0.4200` loss is high and there is some warning

Comment: @Marat for checking how it works I have considered 500 observations and 7703 features

Comment: @Marat `Epoch 4/10
4/4 [==============================] - 180s 45s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.4080
Epoch 5/10
4/4 [==============================] - 172s 42s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.2800`

Comment: I am confused what dimension represents what in the input data

Comment: 7703 are the feature , 500 samples, 1 is the timestep

Comment: what are features and timestep in this example? Sequences of length 1 don't make a lot of sense in context of LSTM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237305/discussion-between-10sha25-and-marat).